# PHPExcel actual value of cell

Tags: phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to read excel values.

I have used

```
$values = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A2:G7');
```

to read the values from A2 to G7. Values are read properly, but the problem is in G column. It is having values that has calculated by formula. So whenever I read the values from G column, I'm not able to get actual value present in cell. I'm getting some other value (may be my code considering formula and executing internally).

While searching for solutions, I noticed that by using `getCalculatedvalue()` I can get actual value.

How to avoid formula and get the actual value from the cell?

How can I use `getCalculatedValue()` when I have used `rangeToArray()` method?

As per the API docs, ie 3rd argument for this method is boolean, TRUE - calculated value, FALSE - Formula. I'm getting result properly, but my problem is I'm not getting the proper result when the formula is using empty cell's value.

For example: Assume excel having 3 columns, ie A B C.

My formula is C2= C1 + B2, C3= C2+ B3. here C1 = empty cell.

```
A        B      C
EMPTY  EMPTY   EMPTY
2        3     3 (C1 + B2)
4        5     8 (C2 + B3)
```

In this case I'm getting C2 = 0 and C3 = 5.

Whats wrong in calculating formula??

Comment: Please don't edit an existing question to ask a new question.... if you have another question to ask, ask it as a new question... otherwise the answer originally provided may bear little resemblance to the question that is displayed making it unhelpful for anybody else

Comment: Sorry Mark, I'm new to this site. so will take time to understand procedures. please inform the solution for my problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the solution to this problem: PHPExcel should correctly calculate the result of C1+B2 as 3, not as 0.... can you post a test Excel file demonstrating this problem to the codeplex site

Comment: There have been some fixes to shared formulae in the latest develop branch on github, please try with that version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument passed to rangeToArray() is a Boolean indicating whether the method should calculate formulae and return the result, or return the formula itself: the default is true; but if you set that argument to false, no calculation will be executed.

This is documented in the API docs:

```
/**
 * Create array from a range of cells
 *
 * @param   string   $pRange             Range of cells (i.e. "A1:B10"), or just one
 *                                           cell (i.e. "A1")
 * @param   mixed    $nullValue          Value returned in the array entry if a cell
 *                                           doesn't exist
 * @param   boolean  $calculateFormulas  Should formulas be calculated?
 * @param   boolean  $formatData         Should formatting be applied to cell values?
 * @param   boolean  $returnCellRef      False - Return a simple array of rows and
 *                                               columns indexed by number counting
 *                                               from zero
 *                                       True - Return rows and columns indexed by
 *                                              their actual row and column IDs
 * @return  array
 */
```